# CouchDB selector query with field filtering

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

We have one huge database in CouchDB and we are doing lot of _find POST to this database using following selector query:

```
{
    "selector":{
        "_id":"123456789"
    },
    "fields":[
        "profile.name",
        "settings",
        "preferences"
    ]
}
```

This query, in heavy load becomes very slow and response time shots to more than 60 sec, even though the selector is _id which is indexed.

My question is:
Is the query becoming slow due to the field filtering?
Should I change this call to GET /db/123456789 and then filter the fields in the client to make it performant?

Comment: Have you tried without the field filtering?

Comment: I would expect it's slow due to rebuilding the index, which happens on read, not write. That's usually what causes slow queries in CouchDB, but without knowing more about your read/write patterns, that's just a guess.

Comment: @AlexisCôté I have not yet tried it without field filtering, just wanted to gather some evidence before doing it.

Comment: @Flimzy does Couchdb rebuild index on every read operation, even though i am queries against _id? Read to write operation ratio is almost 100:1. Read operations are more than write

Comment: It will re-build the index any time documents have changed since the last read, even for `_id`.

Comment: If you do the same query twice in a row, is the second one faster? If so, that's a strong indication that index building is the cause of your slowness.